# Cartopy and matplotlib TypeError: unhashable type: 'MultiLineString'

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to play around a bit with Cartopy by following the examples offered in the official Cartopy website. All of them work correctly but the first

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()

plt.show()
```

All the lines work correctly but as soon as I run the plt.show() command I get the following error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1539, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 278, in resize
    self.show()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 349, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 469, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1079, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mrvaita/python_workspace/gis_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 359, in draw
    inframe=inframe)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2092, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mrvaita/python_workspace/gis_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/feature_artist.py", line 113, in draw
    {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 433, in setdefault
    return self.data.setdefault(ref(key, self._remove),default)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'MultiLineString'
```

Does someone already know anything about that?
My matplotlib version is 1.4.2 and the Cartopy version is 0.13.0

Thank you very much in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an issue reported on the Cartopy issue tracker at https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/682. Basically, Shapely changed the hashability of a geometry between 1.5.12 and 1.5.13. The workaround, until we have a new release of cartopy, is to downgrade your installation of shapely to 1.5.12.

HTH